# MongoDB extra parameter in $lookup, is it possible?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find all active=true from property, and aggregate each record with translation
BUT!!  I only want the english text "gb", not the danish one "dk"

```
property
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "unique" : "ATL-D406",
    "name" : "Atlantis",
    "active" : true
},
{
    "_id" : "222",
    "unique" : "WAT-606",
    "name" : "Wong Amat Tower", 
    "active" : true
}


translation
{
    "_id" : "aaa",
    "language" : "gb",
    "property" : "111",
    "texts" : "Great Condo with Pool View and Balcony"
},
{
    "_id" : "bbb",
    "language" : "dk",
    "property" : "111",
    "texts" : "Lækker Lejlighed med Pool udsigt og Balkon"
},
{
    "_id" : "ccc",
    "language" : "gb",
    "property" : "222",
    "texts" : "Luxury with Direct Beach Front"
},
{
    "_id" : "ddd",
    "language" : "dk",
    "property" : "222",
    "texts" : "Luksus direkte på Stranden"
}
```

As far as I can see, Mongodb only allow one field matching in the $lookup
Is there a way to do this except for the very complex $redact $$KEEP $$PRUNE (which seem like a very complex way of doing it)
Or would I be better off just doing two seperate finds?
Or is there a way to combine the result from two independant finds and project the fields you want?
Like:
 - find all property where active = true
 - find all translate where language = "gb"
 - combine them and project some fields...

```
db.getCollection("property").aggregate(

    // Find all active properties
    { 
        $match: {active:true}
    },

    // Find matching translation record
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "translation",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "property",
            as: "translate"
        }   
    }

)
```

The only way I can think of is to make two finds from js, and then do all the work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to other solutions (than `$$KEEP` and `$$PRUNE`) :

1. unwind results and match the langage you want :

add an **`$unwind`** stage and then filter documents on `translate.langage` field :

```
db.getCollection("property").aggregate([
    {  $match: {active:true}},
    {  $lookup: {
            from: "translation",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "property",
            as: "translate"
        }   
    }, 
    { $unwind: "$translate"}, 
    { $match : {"translate.language": "dk"}}
])
```

2. split the **translation** collection in multiple collection

The other solution would be to have one **translation** collection by langage, for example `translation_en`, `translation_dk` etc.
So you would just have to do the **`$lookup`** on the corresponding langage collection :

```
db.getCollection("property").aggregate([
    {  $match: {active:true}},
    {  $lookup: {
            from: "translation_dk",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "property",
            as: "translate"
        }   
    }
])
```

Note that the second option would be faster

Comment: you missed a "}" on the last line, but other than that it worked perfectly!!  I had no idea you could do $match after $unwind.  And you are right that the second solution is a lot faster, especially when we reach 30 different languages.   Thanks for teaching me something new :-)